# Proofs involving integrals and partitions

Tags: calculus, integration

Last week we had an exam and this was one of the questions:
Let $f:[0,\pi/8] $ be given by $f(x)=sen(4x)$.
Prove that:

a)If $P=\langle x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ is a partition of $[0,\pi/8]$ then $f(\pi/8)-f(0)$ may be written as $f(\pi/8)-f(0)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^ng(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$ for some function $g\in C^\infty$, such that $t_k\in(x_{k-1},x_k)$, for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

b) $g$ can be chosen so that $s(g,P)\leq f(\pi/8)-f(0)\leq S(g,P)$, where $s$ represents inferior sum and $S$ represents superior sum.

c)Using integration theorems, $f(\pi/8)-f(0)=\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/8}g$ and justify this equality is trivial if $g$ is known.

For parts a) and b), I tried using MVT for derivatives, using $g=f'$, although I believe this is not the answer they were looking for (a more general one?)

I couldn't do part c), so I would like to understand it now. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are a Math major? Otherwise, just use Fundamental Calculus Theorem and Mean Value Theorem as arguments.

Comment: Yes, Math Major.

Comment: You may take, for example, the mean value or some specific line of f within the partition. With there are two, there many other functions.

Comment: Well, that certainly doesn't prove c)

Comment: I do not understand c) well. Could you rephrase it to make it clearer than it is on posted statement? My understanding about it is that there is some function g such that its integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{8}$ is the difference between two endpoints evaluations. You say: A number is the sum of areas from its values to the abscisse, which is trivial (input, calculation, output) to known g.